# Characterization of Dirac measure using integrals

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ is a finite measure defined on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, $\mu\not\equiv 0$ and $X$ and uncountable set. Suppose
$$
\int_X fg\,d\mu=\left(\int_X f\,d\mu\right) \left(\int_X g\,d\mu\right)
$$
for all $f,g\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$. Prove that $\mu$ is the Dirac measure on a point.

So far, I have proven that $\mu(X)=1$ and that $\mu(A)\in\{0,1\}\quad \forall\,A\subset X$. Then I tried supposing that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x\in X$, but I did not get anything.

Note: If $X=\mathbb{R}$, then I would construct a decreasing sequence of intervals with measure $1$ and such that their intersection would be a point.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a [measurable cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal) $\kappa$, there is a $\{0,1\}$-valued measure on $\mathcal P(X)$, where $X$ is a set of cardinality $\kappa$, that is not a Dirac measure.  It is relatively consistent with ZFC that there exist no measurable cardinals; it is believed to be relatively consistent that there are (but we can't prove it).

Bottom line: you're not going to be able to prove or disprove this.

Are you sure there wasn't some restriction on $X$?  For example, if $X$ has cardinality $\le c$ it's easy.

Comment: That's a nice but curious construction. I get the point. Is it easy to see how it translates into integrals of $L^1$ functions?

Comment: $\int f d\mu = y$ where $\mu(f^{-1}(\{y\}) =1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\mu(A)\neq 0$ and $\mu(B)\neq 0$ (both finite) for disjoint $A$ and $B$ then using indicator functions
  $$0=\int 1_A 1_B \; d\mu = \int 1_A d\mu \int 1_Bd\mu = \mu(A) \mu(B)\neq 0$$.

Comment: Who says there are disjoint $A$ and $B$ with nonzero measure?

Comment: @RobertIsrael This contradiction says precisely that there aren't.